# Oracle - How to create a table index to match a specific query?

Tags: oracle, indexing, partitioning, sql-execution-plan

I have a query that will run multiple times on a regular interval on a table that has the potential to become very large. I want to ensure that I have an index that can handle my query to make it quicker. I am not very familiar with indexes but so far I have the following query and index:

```
update PERMISSION
SET EXPIRED_FLAG=1
where CASE WHEN VAL_END IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END =1
    AND CURRENT_FLAG=1
    AND SYSDATE+SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR'),2,2)/24> VAL_START+30/1400
    AND EXPIRED_FLAG=0;
```

My index looks like:

```
CREATE INDEX NDX_VAL_DB_CLOSE ON PERMISSION
(CURRENT_FLAG, CASE WHEN VAL_END IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, CASE WHEN EXPIRED_FLAG=0 THEN EXPIRED_FLAG END )
 PCTFREE    10
  INITRANS   2
  MAXTRANS   255
  STORAGE    (
          INITIAL          1M
          NEXT             1M
          MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
          MINEXTENTS       1
          MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
          PCTINCREASE      0
          BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
          FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
          CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
         )
LOGGING
LOCAL (  
  PARTITION NDX_VAL_FKTICKET_ID_PRT1
    LOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE IDX_PRT_01
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   2
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          1M
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            FREELISTS        1
            FREELIST GROUPS  1
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           ),  
   PARTITION NDX_VAL_FKTICKET_ID_PRT2
    LOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE IDX_PRT_02
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   2
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          1M
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            FREELISTS        1
            FREELIST GROUPS  1
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
)
NOPARALLEL;
```

Execution Plan:

[image]

I want to figure out if my index actually matches the query. From looking at the execution plan it appears that my index is being used, but I am not 100% sure the conditions of the index make sense and match the update query fully. Is there anything I can do to the index to have it actually match up with the query or are all the indexed columns already being used? (again, I am completely new to indexing and this is a partitioned table so I am a little lost)

Comment: How selective are the various predicates?  My guess is that the various 1/0 predicates aren't particularly selective and `val_start` is the only reasonably selective predicate in the query.  That is, I'm guessing the `val_start` predicate cuts down the number of rows that need to be updated substantially and the other predicates don't do a lot.  But that's me guessing-- you know your data.  How is the table partitioned?

Comment: In this table, most of the entries will have an expired flag = 1 only a select few will be = 0, even less will be >30min. As for the partition on current flag, that is controlled by a process that I am not too familiar with but as time goes on and more entries are added there will be more entries that get moved to the second partition with current = 0 rather then current = 1 in the active partition that I care about.

Comment: I guess my actual question here is, does this index make any sense given the context of the update query and are all the parameters (predicates) actually being used in the update query shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems your query use another index (NDX_PTP_DB_CLOSE) in place of your index (NDX_VAL_DB_CLOSE). try to use oracle optimizer hint with correct index. if it doesn't use restructure the query.

Comment: Thanks for that, you are right, that was a typo on my part, the index is actually using NDX_VAL_DB_CLOSE now (which is the same as the PTP version, I just renamed it)